# Partial overlapping of image with color

Tags: css

I am trying to accomplish this section of a webpage and am having a difficult time finding a good way to overlap the yellow from the 1st column partially over the 2nd column image. I have set up the columns and have tried using negative properties but that didn't work. I tried adding it to the image in Photoshop but that was a BIG fail. I obviously can't do a border hack with opacity.

Am I missing something? I just can't think of a good way to do this. Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: The easy way to make overlap effect is to use  relative and absolute positioning

Comment: I think you're getting down-voted because you didn't include any code in your question. People like to see what you've tried before coming here for help. Although you've explained what you've tried, there should probably be some code included as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would approach this using absolutely positioned pseudo content within a relatively positioned parent. The following example is missing many details, of course (media queries, better spacing, font treatment, etc.), but is one way to accomplish what you're trying to do.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.leaf {
  background-color: yellow;
  flex: 1;
  position: relative;
  margin: 2.5em 0;
}

.leaf-content {
  padding: 1em 3em 1em 1em;
}

.leaf::after {
  content: '';
  background-color: yellow;
  right: -150px;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 150px;
  opacity: .35;
  position: absolute;
}

.container img {
  width: 500px;
  height: auto;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="leaf">
    <div class="leaf-content">
      <h1>BIKE</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sed est, ipsa minus repellendus, rerum officia eaque, quia pariatur voluptatibus asperiores inventore illum laudantium soluta itaque sit nobis officiis deserunt vero!</p>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="img-container">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1517054612019-1bf855127c43?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=e4814eb541ddb4ef86140974f1bee831&fit=crop&w=1000&h=1000&q=80" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bjg0a6Lv/2/)

Comment: Thanks so much for pointing me in the right direction Andy! Yes, I should have thrown some code up there but was super frustrated.